# NodeJS 12 application on macbook pro M1

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

do you have someone a solution for this problem?

The problem is on my nodejs application on new MacBook pro M1. I have a project built on nodejs 12 and enabled ES2015 import/export class. On my old MacBook, everything works fine but on my new mac book with M1 chip, I see in the console log where I try to run application errors about imports and extends of import files.
I tried to start the application with **--experimental-modules, package.json “type” = "module"**. I use babel. Babel looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

and my run command is NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/app.js --exec babel-node

Error is:

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND] [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/xxxxx/Documents/projects/svj/svj-aplikace-backend/index' imported from /Users/xxxxx/Documents/projects/svj/svj-aplikace-backend/bin/app.js
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:308:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:731:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:842:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:76:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

Any ideas? If someone needs more information, I will provide it.

Thank you